# Move Laravel storage folder to Amazon s3

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In the Laravel `app/` folder, there is another folder called `storage/` which keeps all data, logs, and caches. I was wondering if there any way to change the location of this storage directory to Amazon s3 instead of its current location?

Comment: This has significant performance impact and I'd generally recommend against it pretty strongly. There's likely a better way, but it depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I guess making a sub domain (cdn.yourdomain.com), adding it to amazon cache and getting js, css and images from that is not a bad idea. I've done this and it made the site quite faster. If you are storing data other than these types on your storage getting those is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is doable but it is most probably a terrible idea and I recommend that you never use S3 for hosting your logs, etc.

Leave it where it is, Changing it would have an enormous negative impact on your performance